# Parse timestamp of tomcat logfile in go

Tags: tomcat, go, timestamp

I am trying to parse the timestamp of a tomcat logfile in go, but it doesn't go through.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    date := "26/Nov/2017:19:23:15 +0000"
    fmt.Println(time.Parse(time.RFC822Z, date))
}
```

And the error message is the following.

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "26/Nov/2017:19:23:15 +0000" as "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700": cannot parse "/Nov/2017:19:23:15 +0000" as " "
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have`date := "26/Nov/2017:19:23:15 +0000"` and layout  `RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"`. How could that possibly work?

Comment: @peterSO Any ideas how to parse it properly then?

Comment: See [package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) under Constants for instructions: "To define your own format, write down what the reference time would look like formatted your way;."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has a rather unique way of time formatting time.  Templates need to be based on the following date (which can be remembered as it loosely follows 1,2,3,4,5,6,7):

> Jan 2, 2006 3:04:05 PM -0700

To create a custom format, you create a string that matches how the above date would be formatted.  In your case `02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700`

```
func main() {
    date := "26/Nov/2017:19:23:15 +0000"
    parsedTime, _ := time.Parse("02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700", date)
    fmt.Println(parsedTime) 
}
// Outputs: 2017-11-26 19:23:15 +0000 UTC
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6nene8tnZL